# Apache mod_proxy configuration - URI patterns

Tags: apache, apache2, mod-proxy

I want to know the difference between the following apache mod_proxy configurations to resolve an issue.  I need to forward a HTTP request like following URL from Apache web server to a remote Sun One server.

http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/app_enu/start.swe?param1=test1&param2=test2

I configured the mod_proxy as follows

(a).

```
ProxyPass /app_enu/  http://<IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT>/app_enu/

ProxyPassReverse /app_enu/  http://<IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT>/app_enu/
```

But the URL is not working properly (not invoking the service as I expected – **start.swe**).
I want to know what is the difference between above model (a) and following model (1), (2) and (3).

```
 1. ProxyPass /app_enu/*  http://<IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT>/app_enu/
 2. ProxyPass /app_enu/  http://<IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT>/app_enu/*
 3. ProxyPass /app_enu/*  http://<IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT>/app_enu/*
```

Appreciate the help to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards are implied already on both parameters. Don't use them at all in the configuration.  If you want finer grained control, use ProxyPassMatch.